# Facebook GraphAPI via another webpage php?

Tags: php, path, include, require

First: please forgive me - Im a bit of a novice as some of this...

I have a working test site which is running the php facebook SDK to perform some simple graphAPI requests successfully. Namely read a group's feed, which the user is a member of, and process this and display it back on a webpage.

This all works fine, the problem I have encountered is when trying to perform the same request via a php curl POST to another webpage (on the same domain). It seems that the SDK does not carry the expected session to another page when a post request is formed (see "AUTH ERROR2" in code)...this works fine when the following file is included via a "require_once" but not when a curl is made.

I would much rather do a "curl" as Im finding when a "require_once" is done from a page in a different directory level, Im getting php errors of the page not being found - which is expected.

I may just be tackling this problem all wrong...there may be a simpler way to make sure when files are includes, their correct directly level remains intact, or there may be a way to send over the currently authorised facebook sdk session via a curl post. All of which I have tried to no avail, and I would really appreciate any help or advise on this.

Thank you for your time.

```
//readGroupPosts.inc.php
function readGroupPosts($postVars)

{
 //$access_token = $postVars[0]; 
 // ^-- I'm presuming I need this? I have been experimenting appending it to 
 //     the graphAPI request to no success...
 $groupID = $postVars[1];
 $limit = $postVars[2];

 require_once("authFb.inc.php"); //link to the facebookSDK & other stuff

  if ($user) {
   try {
     $groupFeed = $facebook->api("/$groupID/feed?limit=$limit"); //limit=0 returns all; 
     $groupFeed = $groupFeed['data']; //removes first tier of array for simpler access


     $postArray;
     for($i=0; $i<count($groupFeed); $i++)
      {
       $postArray[$i] = array($groupFeed[$i]['from']['name'], $groupFeed[$i]['message'], $groupFeed[$i]['updated_time'], count($groupFeed[$i]['likes']['data']));
      }

     return $postArray;
   } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
     error_log($e);
     $user = null;
     return "AUTH ERROR1"; //for testing..
   }  
  }
 else
  {
     return "AUTH ERROR2"; //no user is authenticated i.e. $user == null..
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I would much rather do a "curl" as Im finding when a "require_once" is done from a page in a different directory level, Im getting php errors of the page not being found - which is expected.
>
> I may just be tackling this problem all wrong...

Definitively.

Using cURL as a “workaround” just because you’re not able to find your way around your server’s file system is an *outrageous* idea. Don’t do it. Stop even thinking about it. Now.

> there may be a simpler way to make sure when files are includes, their correct directly level remains intact

Yes – for example, to use absolute paths instead of relative ones. Prefixing the path with the value of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` for example – that way, once you’ve given the path correctly in respect to this “base path”, it does not matter *where* you’re requiring the file from, because an absolute path is the same no matter from where you look at it.

---

*(And since this is not a Facebook-related problem at all, but just concerns basics of PHP and server-side programming, I’ll edit the tags.)*